# Two warnings in code meant to implement a stack using linked list

Tags: c

I have three files: stack2.h, stack2.c, and main.c.

stack2.h contains this:

```
/* Define linked list structure */
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
} Node, *pNode;

/* Define stack structure */
typedef struct StackType {
    pNode top;
} Stack, *pStack;

/* Declare functions */
pStack InitStack( );

int IsEmpty( pStack pS );
int Pop( pStack pS );

void Push( pStack pS, int val );
void KillStack( pStack pS );
```

stack2.c contains

```
pStack InitStack( ) {

    /* Declare variables */
    pStack pS = (pStack)malloc( sizeof(Stack) );

    /* Set first node to NULL */
    pS -> top = NULL;

    /* Return pointer to stack */
    return pS;

}

int IsEmpty( pStack pS ) {

    return ( pS->top == NULL );

}

int Pop( pStack pS ) {

    /* Declare variables */
    int ret = 0;
    pNode temp = NULL;

    /* Check if stack is empty */
   if( IsEmpty( pS ) ) {
        printf( "[ERROR] Pop operation on an empty stack.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    /* Find return value (last in) */
    ret = pS->top->val;
    temp = pS->top;

    /* Delete and kill node */
    pS->top = pS->top->next;
    free( temp );

    /* Return */
    return ret;

}

void Push( pStack pS, int val ) {

    /* Allocate memory for new node */
    pNode nnew = (pNode)malloc( sizeof(Node) );

    /* Initiate node */
    nnew->next = pS->top;
    nnew->val = val;

    /* Set structure's top to new node */
    pS -> top = nnew;

}
```

I won't burden you with what main.c contains. In essence, it includes the correct libraries and files, and simply pushes and pops some values. I get these warnings:

```
assignment from incompatible pointer types
```

on these two lines:

```
    nnew->next = pS->top;
    pS->top = pS->top->next;
```

I'm a bit confused. nnew is a pointer to a node, so that nnew->next is a pointer to a node, too. pS is a pointer to a stack, so pS->top is a pointer to a node, too. I don't see how these are incompatible!

What is going on over here? Thanks!

Comment: You should specify the FILE and LINE NUMBER that generates the error.

Comment: `struct node` and `struct Node` are not the same thing.

Comment: @geekosaur: two copy-and-pastes and that description and you've got a pretty decent answer there...

Comment: Sure, I just like to hope the OP will see what I'm getting at and derive the correct answer themselves.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
} Node, *pNode;
```

You declare `struct node` but use `struct Node *` within it; C is case sensitive, the pointers therefore are *not* the same type.  C, perhaps unfortunately, will happily let you manipulate pointers to unknown `struct` types as long as you don't dereference them (it's an idiom used for "opaque pointers"), so the only warning you get of this is the pointer type mismatch.

Comment: Ah! I accidentally wrote "struct Node *next" when I meant "Node *next" :) I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain about the fact that "struct Node" doesn't exist. I feel like that is something that it should have picked up!

Thank you very much!